# List of notable security breaches

Tags: risk-analysis

Is there a list of notable  (i.e. those reported in the mainstream media) security issues such as hacks, viruses, worms and any other unauthorized or improper access or use of computers for malicious purpose?

A Wiki to keep track for posterity would be ideal.

Comment: This could be answered with a very quick Google search.

Comment: @Graham Lee: I beg to differ, particularly from a posterity perspective. I'd be grateful to be proven wrong, but none of my Google searches give me any accessible list that includes e.g. 2011's Anonymous & Sony PSN, Wikileaks & US DFA, LulzSec & Arizona Police etc., much less for 2010 going backwards.

Comment: Closed as too localised, and in any case, a very quick google throws up all the recent ones for me. @Brian - your google-fu is faulty today:-)

Comment: @Rory: What about those breaches that aren't recent? That's where Google fails, hard, regardless of -fu. :)

Comment: @Brian - closed again after discussion. The question isn't really providing anything useful - datalossdb hosts lists. You could redo the question to ask for places where lists are hosted, but as it stands we would be too time localised and not offering anything over and above datalossdb.

Comment: @Rory: The proposed list is not on those web-sites. Also beg to differ on SE's suitability for lists:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812 (though both have caveats about suitability for SE sites); Finally, I think you are misusing "too localized", see http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/536 ; there might be another reason why this question isn't suitable, but localized isn't it :)

Comment: To my mind resources for trend analysis and a historical situational understanding of security threats are valuable to security professionals.  Time for me to review the FAQ as this closure is not the first to strike me as strange.

Comment: I agree with @briant-m-hunt there are significant cases that are not recent and not easily locatable with google. Using a variety of search terms I was not able to come up with one incident involving Kevin Mitnick, who had several notable incidents. I also agree with zedman9991. Those new to the field deserve to learn about John Draper (Capn' Crunch), and that Woz practiced soldering by making blue boxes.

Answer (score 5):

A good source focused on publicly announced data loss is - http://datalossdb.org/

Comment: This is a great reference, and would be a suitable answer if only you could grep out the security breaches reported by the mainstream media.

Comment: @Brian: There are filters, try for example http://datalossdb.org/index/most_discussed or http://datalossdb.org/index/largest

Comment: Good resource but it is missing a couple decades. Aparently nobody lost data before 2001.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at: [Largest data breaches of all time graphic](http://1raindrop.typepad.com/1_raindrop/2011/06/largest-data-breaches-of-all-time-graphic.html)

Answer (score -2):

### 2011

- [Sony Playstation Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_Network_outage) by [Anonymous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_%28group%29)
- [1 million Sony user accounts](http://money.cnn.com/2011/06/02/technology/sony_lulz_hack/?section=money_latest) by [LulzSec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LulzSec)
- "Cablegate" – [250,000 US Embassy Diplomatic Cables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_diplomatic_cables_leak)

### 2009

- [Operation Aurora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Aurora) - Google

### 2008

- [US Military officially hacked](http://greathistory.com/largest-security-breach-ever-of-us-military-computers-confirmed.htm) - "first confirmed on-the-record penetration of U.S. military classified computer systems by a foreign intelligence agency"

### 2000

- [Jonathan James](http://www.howstuffworks.com/framed.htm?parent=10-famous-hackers-hacks.htm&url=http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2009/07/hacker/) (aka *C0mrade*) hacks NASA and the Department of Defence
- The [ILOVEYOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILOVEYOU) virus infects millions of computers

### 1996

- Griffas Air Force Base hacked by [Matthew Bevan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathew_Bevan) and Richard Price

### 1995

- [Vladimir Levin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Levin) transfers $10 million from Citibank to his own accounts

### 1988

- [The Morris Worm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morris_worm) - brings down 1/10th of the internet

### 1987

- [Christmas Tree EXEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_Tree_EXEC) - “the first widely distributed disruptive computer worm”

### 1982

- [Elk Cloner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elk_Cloner) - “The first known microcomputer virus that spread "in the wild"”

### 1960's

- [2600 hertz tone from Cap'n Crunch cereal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2600%3a_The_Hacker_Quarterly) used for phreaking free phone calls

Comment: Thats it, nothing before 2008? I love the 2001 Erroneous Issued Digital Certificates, where a couple individual claiming to be microsoft employees got VeriSign Class 3 code-signing digital certificates in Microsoft's name.

Comment: @this.josh: It's a wiki, editable by those with more time and better memories. ;)